# How to know what you're downloading

Tags: java, android

In my application, I would like the user to be able to submit a direct URL of an archive file specific to my application. Currently, my application has no problem receiving the link, fixing any small URL issues, downloading, unarchiving and reading the data. The problem lies in downloading files/pages that aren't the right type.

Since anything could both have the extension of my archive type or be a web page/page not found (as per a bad URL) and my application is none-the-wiser.

How can I ensure that the application is downloading the proper file before trying to unarchive the wrong type of file? I've thought about MIME-Type, but it seems as though that isn't consistent with the archives.

Comment: "How can I ensure that the application is downloading the proper file before trying to unarchive the wrong type of file?" - Don't let the users directly enter a URL. Give them a list to pick from, or some other subset of all possible URLs. Can you explain a bit more about your application? I can't figure out why the user would need to type in a URL to a data file, that your application won't know about so it can't reference it against a list of known good URLs

Comment: @FoamyGuy Unfortunately, due to NDAs, I can't disclose too much. The reason why a person would put in the URL directly is for usability. Yes, they could enter the URL into the browser, but this allows for the user to also perform the action within the app (Some people have mentioned to add it). However, entering the URL in the browser and that opening the application, again, would have similar issues if the file isn't the correct type, or specifically in my case, an archive. And the reason why the URLs aren't predetermined is because nearly anyone can create this type of file.

Comment: I don't personally see a way around your problem them. If the user is free to enter whatever they want. And there is no list of known good URLs, nor is there anything distinctive about the files being downloaded then your app has no way to know whether any given file is good or bad without doing the leg work of unarchiving it and having a look at what it contains.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Okay. Thats what I thought. Thanks! I'll talk to them about removing the feature to prevent those issues.